# Printing text in recursion

Tags: recursion

I am working on writing a recursive command for calculating the Ackermann function. Throughout the calculation, I would like to print out some text. However, I am unable to do so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ackermann}[2]{
    \ifnum#1=0
        % case1
        % comment me in
        \the\numexpr(#2+1)\relax
    \else
        \ifnum#2=0
            % case 2
            % comment me in
            \ackermann{\the\numexpr(#1-1)\relax}{1}
        \else
            % case 3
            % comment me in
            \ackermann{\the\numexpr(#1-1)\relax}{\ackermann{#1}{\the\numexpr(#2-1)\relax}}
        \fi
    \fi
}


\begin{document}

\ackermann{2}{2}

\end{document}
```

Above is the MWE that I use. It works as expected when you use it as is, but when you uncomment one of the `%comment me in` comments, it suddenly starts misbehaving and I fail to understand why it does. Could somebody maybe explain this behaviour to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test `\ifnum#2=0` assumes `#2` expands to a number but  in the second recursive call `#2` is `\ackermann{#1}{\the\numexpr(#2-1)\relax}` which if you uncomment `comment me in` has an expansion that starts with `c` so you get the error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   c
```